# Usuario logado android

Tags: android

No meu app, preciso alterar o menu entre três tipos dependendo do tipo de usuario logado. Como ainda nao tenho um banco para verificar essa informacao, gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de armazenar esse nome do usuario para exibir o tipo de menu correto.

Hoje eu ja consigo passar o nome do usuario da tela de login para a home, mas ao trocar de tela a variavel que tem o nome do usuario e limpa.

Comment: Como Você faz isso? Poderia mostrar para que alguém possa ajudar?

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 1):

Como é para **fins de teste** (porque ainda nao tem banco), você pode criar um Singleton ao iniciar o aplicativo. Esse objeto armazena informações estáticas, o que significa que você pode acessar de qualquer lugar do aplicativo.

```
    public class SingletonUsuario {

        private static SingletonUsuario instance = null;
        private static Usuario usuario = null;

        public static SingletonUsuario getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                usuario = new Usuario();
                return instance = new SingletonUsuario();
            } else {
                return instance;
            }
        }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        SingletonUsuario.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return SingletonUsuario.usuario;
    }
}
```

Para usá-lo, é só chamar:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario();
u.setNome("Joãozinho");
SingletonUsuário.getInstance.setUsuario(u);
```

Para pegar a informação **de qualquer lugar do aplicativo**

```
txtView.setText(SingletonUsuario.getInstance.getUsuario.getNome); // retorna a string nome
```

Desta forma, em qualquer activity seu usuário estará "gravado" na memória ram e não desaparecerá até que o aplicativo seja encerrado.

Answer (score 0):

O Android oferece muitas maneiras de armazenar dados de uma aplicação. Um deste modo é chamado de [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), que permitem guardar e recuperar dados em forma de chave. Veja um exemplo:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "USUARIO";
SharedPreferences  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Para recuperar o valor você usa:

```
settings.getString(PREFS_NAME, "")
```

Detalhes

- [Shared Preferences Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
- [Android SharedPreferences Tutorial and Example](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/)